# Reinstall Window Blinds, Screw Holes

Tags: drywall, windows, screws, blinds

I purchased Inside-Mount Horizontal Faux Wood Blinds.
We removed our blinds temporarily due to painting. When reinstalling, should we reuse the Same holes, use different drywall screw mounts, or get blinds with different measurements?

How do I make holes as secure when reinstall or is it something I should not worry about? Thanks

Screws: 1-¼” #8 Hex Head x

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your substrate? Hard to tell from the photo.

Comment: I've had good success just squeezing a bit of construction adhesive into the holes and reusing the same screws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of drywall mounting fasteners. Some, like the three on the left, below, tend to leave the screw-holding part in the wall, and can be reused as-is.

The two on the right, a toggle bolt and a plastic plug, drop down inside the wall, or break apart after removal of the bolt, and usually need to be replaced with new hardware.

[image: Drywall fasteners]

If you cannot tell if the reinforcing part is still in the wall, but the wallboard is intact, just reuse the holes; enlarging them slightly for the next size larger fastener. My experience is that the plastic expansion plug is more likely to pull loose than the other types. Note the weight for which the fastener is designed, usually shown on the package, and allow for a *bit more than weight of blinds alone*, because one pulls on blinds and shades frequently.

Comment: are you saying for the third anchor in the middle, next time I remodel, I can unscrew the blinds, and then place new screws into the existing anchor without any damage to holes? seems like it should work?

Comment: I am reading that drywall anchors are not reusable, looking for a reusable solution next time I remodel if possible    ,  "The reason for this is that the screws and anchors are a unit. When you installed them, both the screw and the anchor were pushed into the wall at the same time. This caused them to be joined together tightly. Over time, the screws can become damaged and the heads can become stripped, but they are still not coming out by themselves."  https://remodelingmate.com/can-you-remove-and-reuse-drywall-anchors/